# Warning AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CompletionListElementID is obsolete: Instead of passing in CompletionListElementID, use the default

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, warnings, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I really can not understand this problem. When i publish my asp.net 4.0 website it shows this error.

**Warning   'AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CompletionListElementID' is obsolete: 'Instead of passing in CompletionListElementID, use the default flyout and style that using the CssClass properties.'**

Now i am going to provide the element it shows as warning.

```
   <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx2" ID="AutoCompleteExtender4"
    TargetControlID="txtPokemonName" ServicePath="AutoCompleteName.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionListPokemonName"
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="500" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="25"
    CompletionListCssClass="AutoExtender" CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoExtenderList"
    CompletionListElementID="DIVAutoExtender2" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AutoExtenderHighlight"
    DelimiterCharacters=";, :" ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
    <Animations>
        <OnShow>
            <Sequence>
                <OpacityAction Opacity="0" />
                <HideAction Visible="true" />
                <ScriptAction Script="
                    // Cache the size and setup the initial size
                    var behavior = $find('AutoCompleteEx2');
                    if (!behavior._height) {
                        var target = behavior.get_completionList();
                        behavior._height = target.offsetHeight - 2;
                        target.style.height = '0px';
                    }" />
                                           <Parallel Duration=".4">
                    <FadeIn />
                    <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValue="0" EndValueScript="$find('AutoCompleteEx2')._height" />
                </Parallel>
            </Sequence>
        </OnShow>
        <OnHide>               
            <Parallel Duration=".4">
                <FadeOut />
                <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValueScript="$find('AutoCompleteEx2')._height" EndValue="0" />
            </Parallel>
        </OnHide>
    </Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Now what does visual studio want me to fix and why showing this warning ?

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Visual Studio 2010 , C# 4.0 , Asp.net 4.0 , Asp.net website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an old (deprecated) attribute of the `AutoCompleteExtender`.  The `CompletionListElementID` attribute is no longer supported.  These are the styling attributes you should use (from [the AutoCompleteExtender documentation page](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)):

- **CompletionListCssClass** - Css Class that will be used to style the completion list flyout.
- **CompletionListItemCssClass** - Css Class that will be used to style an item in the AutoComplete list flyout.
- **CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass** - Css Class that will be used to style a highlighted item in the AutoComplete list flyout.

**Note:** `CompletionListItemCssClass` is the one that has replaced `CompletionListElementID`

They really provide all the flexibility you need.  Happy coding!